# C++ Deleting an object in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2015, erase

I am currently using a vector to hold the people in a program. I am trying to delete it with

`vectorname.erase(index);`

I pass the vector in a function, as well as the element that I want to delete. My main problem is how can I improve my code in terms of compilation speed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class person {
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        person() {}
        person(string n):name(n){}
        const string GetName() {return name;}
        void SetName(string a) { name = a; }
};

void DeleteFromVector(vector<person>& listOfPeople,person target) {
    for (vector<person>::iterator it = listOfPeople.begin();it != listOfPeople.end();++it) {//Error 2-4
        if (it->GetName() == target.GetName()) {
            listOfPeople.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    //first group of people
    person player("Player"), assistant("Assistant"), janitor("Janitor"), old_professor("Old Professor");

    //init of vector
    vector<person> listOfPeople = { player, assistant, janitor, old_professor };

    DeleteFromVector(listOfPeople, janitor);
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining iterator in `for`, but not using it?

Comment: You're doing this all wrong. You're using `erase` but not taking its return value as the new iterator, so after that you're using invalid, corrupt iterators. And, there's a much better way to do it which you can see here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: OK, I see your `break` immediately after using `erase` so I guess you're not using invalid iterators after all.

Comment: Instead of all that stuff, just use `find_if` to find the janitor and erase using it's return value. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f004aab3525a942a).

Comment: Why do you use both `it` and `index`.  The whole point of an iterator is to use it instead of an index.  Pick one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to define `index`, iterator can be used to access objects in vector:

```
for (vector<person>::iterator it = listOfPeople.begin(); it != listOfPeople.end(); ++it) {//Error 2-4
    if (it->GetName() == target.GetName()) {
        listOfPeople.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
```

> Since next line is to break for loop, we don't consider invalid iterator problem here.

Comment: Next line is to break for loop, should we still need to consider invalid iterator problem?

Comment: Ah, that would avoid the problem.

Comment: @MartinZhai Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need that loop to delete the object from the vector.  Just use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
void DeleteFromVector(vector<person>& listOfPeople, const person& target) 
{
    // find the element
    auto iter = std::find_if(listOfPeople.begin(), listOfPeople.end(),
                             [&](const person& p){return p.GetName() == target.GetName();});

    // if found, erase it
    if ( iter != listOfPeople.end())
       listOfPeople.erase(iter);
}
```

Comment: This one is better than the accepted answer - use the std::find_if instead of doing the work yourself.  And if there is operator == defined for the person class you can use std::find()

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the "p" object in the return line and the "target" is causing errors.

Error (active) the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "person::GetName"
Error (active) the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "person::GetName"
Error C2662 'std::string person::GetName(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const person' to 'person &'

Comment: @CraftedGaming Then either remove the `const` or make `GetName()` a const function.  Better to make it a `const` function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I changed the function into a const however it still contains the same set of errors

Comment: @CraftedGaming -- It compiles with no errors [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60da3d99c6b0472f)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Screw it. It's not compiling on my side. I'm still going to use the first answer

Comment: @CraftedGaming -- Maybe you're not using a C++ 11 compiler?  What compiler are you using?  It also compiles with no errors [using Visual Studio 2015](http://rextester.com/BIOB98935).  So if you're not getting it to compile, you need to look into why, as your compiler may be broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
listOfPeople.erase(
                   remove(listOfPeople(), listOfPeople.end(), target),
                   listOfPeople.end()
                  )
```

"remove" operation in this erase-remove idiom will move all the elements except target to the front of the vector range and "erase" operation will delete all elements that are at the end that satisfies the target criteria. This is much efficient even though it is not as expressive as iterative version.

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks both. answer is now updated with explanation.